# Natural Occurrences of Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I am wondering why so many stats are normally distributed. For example, a typical example is that the heights of people in a university are likely to be normally distributed. One driver of normal distribution is of course the CLT. But the height example seems not connected to the CLT.

Comment: In the example you site it may be a good approximation.  Since there are no negative heights it can't be exactly normal.

Comment: There is probably a duplicate somewhere on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the height example is related to the CLT. The reason why the normal distribution is so common is because (as per the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) article) 'averages of random variables independently drawn from independent distributions converge in distribution to the normal'

Height has lots of random variables - genetics, diet, pollution, and tons of other effects. It's the concert of all of these small effects that can lead something like height to be normally distributed.